# How to use “should” to express surprise and expectation respectively?

Tags: expressions, should

*The value should be zero* can be read as two totally different meanings:

1. The value is zero, and we have expected that it would be zero.
2. The value is zero. But we have never expected that it would be zero.

How to use *should* to express surprise and expectation respectively like this case?

Comment: Are you asking for the sentences to be rewritten to express those meanings unambiguously? I expect you also know that that sentence is also available even if the value is not zero.

Comment: I would never use your meaning 2: do you mean "The value is not zero, although we expected it to be"? If so, the question seems to dissipate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In US English, the sentence *The value should be zero* can mean

> - The value is not known, but it is expected it will be zero.
> - The value is known, but is not zero, contrary to expectations.

It would not mean

> The value is known to be zero, and it was expected to be zero.

The conditional or subjunctive *should* creates either an ambiguity or contrast, rather than a declarative sense.

If you wanted to be clearer that the value is not zero, contrary to expectations, you could say

> The value should have been zero.

Obviously, context may provide clarification, especially if it conveys whether the speaker is aware of the value.

Comment: Well, there is the protestation case when the value is zero, was predicted to be zero, and somebody else has expressed surprise or doubt. In that case, the obvious rejoinder would be, "[t]he value *should* be zero."

Comment: @bye Agreed. Good catch. Again, that's why context is important.